# WooCommerce: ACF value not pulling through product category

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, advanced-custom-fields

I created custom fields for a WooCommerce category. Location shown below & they work correctly.

[image: Woocommerce category ACF fields]

However, when I go to my `archive.php` file and attempt a `the_field('category_banner)`, it retrieves no data. Here is an example of how I've laid it out.

```
<?php
$categorybanner      = get_field('category_banner');
$categorydescription = get_field('category_description');
?>

<div class="container-fluid" id="ivy-banner" style="background: url('<?php echo $categorybanner ?>') center / cover"></div>
<h4 class="text-black"><?php echo $categorydescription; ?></h4>
```

Any reason why this code doesn't work? I can only assume it has got something to do with the location rather than the code itself. How can I circumvent this?

Comment: what is your exact requirement? Do you want to add image and description to woocommerce product categories and then want to get those values somewhere in page?

Comment: Pretty much yes! So I've created/assigned the ACF fields to WooCommerce Categories. I've filled those fields in, and when I try to use "the_field()" & such. The data just doesn't pull. I don't understand why.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Please try the below Code. It may help you to get the values.

```
    <?php
  $term = get_queried_object();
  $categorybanner      = get_field('category_banner', $term);
  $categorydescription = get_field('category_description', $term);
?>

<div class="container-fluid" id="ivy-banner" style="background: url('<?php echo $categorybanner ?>') center / cover"></div>
<h4 class="text-black"><?php echo $categorydescription; ?></h4>
```

Comment: Wow, wow, wow!
Pullata, this was SUCH a simple solution. Fantastic, thank you SO much!