# ACF Banner Image on WooCommerce Shop Page & Fallback Banner Image for Product Search Results Page

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, advanced-custom-fields, acfpro

I'm using Advanced Custom Fields to display individual banner images for each product category as outlined in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54350020/woocommerce-acf-value-not-pulling-through-product-category).

To do this, I've added the following to my `archive-product.php`:

```
<?php
/** Product Category Banner Image **/
$term = get_queried_object();
$image  = get_field('prod_cat_banner_image', $term);
?>

    <header id="title-banner" class="product-cat" style="background-image: linear-gradient(0deg,rgba(24,27,52,0.5),rgba(24,27,52,0.5)), url('<?php echo $image; ?>')">
        <div class="container">
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col align-self-center">
                    <h1 class="entry-title"><?php woocommerce_page_title(); ?>.</h1>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </header>
```

This works great for [product category pages](https://nextrack.com.au/product-category/dust-management-controls/) but won't display the banner image on the [main shop page](https://nextrack.com.au/products/) even though I have the field group added to its location:

[Screenshot of ACF Field Group Location](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nviS8.png)

How can I get the banner image to display on the main WooCommerce shop page and is there a way to set a fallback banner image to display on the [product search results page](https://nextrack.com.au/?s=dustex&post_type=product)?

Comment: You can check if the image is empty with - `if(!$image){}` and then `$image  = get_field('prod_cat_banner_image', get_the_ID());` instead

Comment: If I'm adding an image to the shop page, I use the customizer and add a custom item in there.

Comment: Thanks @Stender - PHP noob here so forgive me if this makes no sense but I've tried to the following to no avail:

`<?php if (!$image): ?>
    <?php $image = get_bloginfo( 'stylesheet_directory') . '/img/banner-default.jpg'; ?>
<?php else :
    $image  = get_field('prod_cat_banner_image', get_the_ID()); ?>
<?php endif; ?>`